# Slanting form of proper names like book titles

Tags: word-form

In other languages like Russian or Chinese, book titles are presented inside signs like 《Bible》， but in English there is no such a sign and the book titles are printed in slant *Bible* to make a difference. But under some conditions, when no slant form can be made possible, how can these book titles be known to the readers that they are book titles?

Comment: Conversely; If you are not Russian or Chinese how can you know that 《Bible》means a book title?

Comment: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/underline-or-italicize-book-titles/ I think this should answer you question adequately.

Answer (score 4):

The correct name of "slant" is *italic*.

If italic is not usable for some reason, normal practice is to use single, or sometimes double quotes.

> The name of the book is 'Uses of Italic Font'.

Answer (score 3):

As Brad pointed out in a comment, if *italics* are not available, [underlining](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/288987/) is an alternative. If neither are possible (you will note that underlining is not supported on Stack Exchange unless I trick it by making a dummy link) you will have to explore other possibilities, such as printing the titles in ALL CAPS or setting them off in "quotation marks."

It is common practice to italicize *major* or *longer* works, such as:

- Book titles
- Album titles
- Play/musical titles
- Named artwork (whether painting, sculpture, etc)

Shorter works are printed in roman (non-italic) font, and set off with quotation marks; these include

- Chapter titles within a book
- Scene names within a play (though these are usually numbered instead)
- Song names

Comment: Also names of ships, named aircraft, cars, etc, may be italicised. In 1899 Camille Jenatzy was the first to go over 100 kM/hr in his car La Jamais Contente. –

Comment: I haven't seen book titles put in ALL CAPS before. Quotation marks, yes.

Comment: @gotube I often see theatrical titles rendered in all caps, particularly in actor/designer bios in playbills—the bios are all submitted to a single person who compiles them in the playbill, and who may not be trusted to properly italicize titles.

Answer (score 2):

《 and 》 are a form of quotation mark.  English quotation marks are either like this " " or like this ' '.

Best practice is to put books' titles in italics:

> *Great Expectations* by Charles Dickens

But where this is not possible - or when writing by hand - another alternative is to use quotation marks:

> "Great Expectations" by Charles Dickens

Larry Trask at Sussex University [says](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/quotes/titles):

> A couple of generations ago, it was the custom to enclose all titles in quotation marks: titles of books, titles of poems, titles of films, titles of newspapers, and so on. This usage, however, has now largely disappeared, and the modern custom is to write most titles in italics. But in academic circles, at least, it is still usual to enclose the titles of articles in journals and magazines in quotes, as well as the titles of chapters in books ... It is still not exactly wrong to refer to a newspaper as 'The Guardian', or to a book as 'Uncle Tom's Cabin', but it is certainly old-fashioned now, and my advice is to use italics rather than quotation marks, except perhaps when you are writing by hand.

All that said, the word "Bible" should be neither italicised nor put in quotation marks:

> The Bible, books within it, versions of it, and other sacred writings are the exceptions to the rule: these are books you do not underline or italicize.

The [above](https://public.wsu.edu/%7Edelahoyd/bible.doc.html) is from a page describing MLA style rules, but as far as I know, it reflects standard practice across the board.  However, if you were citing a specific edition of the Bible, the title of that Bible *would* go in italics.